# Create a class with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page I create an instance of a `class (MyClass)`, this class has 2 methods. But I'd like to do 2 things :

1. In **(1)**, set the value `this.message`
2. In **(2)**, call the information method or another method of the class

Thank,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myClass = new MyClass("MyParam");
        $('#Target').click(function (event) {
            myClass.save("Test");
        });
    }); 
</script>

function MyClass(myParam) {
    this.myParam = myParam;
    this.isError = false;
    this.message = "";
}

// Define the class methods.
MyClass.prototype = {
    save: function (action) {
        **(2)**
    },
    information: function (action) {
        **(1)**
    }
};
```

**Update1**

When I execute the code below the `data` value in `information` is show as `undifined`

```
MyClass.prototype = {

    click: function (action) {
        var myData;
        $.post(....., $("form").serialize(),
            function (data) {
                myData = data;
            });

        this.isError = this.information(myData);
    },

    information: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: A basic example, showing how to set properties, or call random methods: Inside `save`: `this.message = action;`. Inside `information`: `return this.hasOwnProperty(action) && typeof this[action] === 'function' && this[action]();`. Your question is somewhat vague, hence the possibility that you're looking for a slightly different bit of code.

Comment: You probably don't want to assign the prototype to an object literal since you're wiping out it's default contents like the constructor reference. Instead add each function as a separate member like MyClass.prototype.save = ... & MyClass.prototype.information = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `save` and `information` functions, `this` should be the current `MyClass` object.

So, inside `save`, `this.message` should work, and inside `information`, `this.save()` should work.

UPDATE:

```
click: function (action) {
    var myData;
    $.post(....., $("form").serialize(),
        function (data) {
            myData = data;
        });

    this.isError = this.information(myData);
}
```

`$.post` is an AJAX request and is ran asynchronously.  Meaning that `this.isError = this.information(myData);` is ran *before* it finishes, therefore `myData` is `undefined`.  You need to call `this.information` from inside the callback.

Inside the callback, `this` will no longer be your `MyClass` object, so we need to save a reference to it.  Like this:

```
click: function (action) {
    var that = this;
    $.post(....., $("form").serialize(),
        function (data) {
            that.isError = that.information(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: I'd like assign data content (where there is that.isError) to a variable of my class

Comment: Thanks you help, not work yet. I place the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Kris_I/fBjz6/1/ (easier) In the document ready, I create an instance with a parameter in argument, I assign a method from the class to the click event of a button. I'd like after click get the value view and isViewError.

Comment: @Kris-I: Your `alert`s are firing before the AJAX call is done.  Put the code dealing with the data in the callback.

Comment: @Kris-I: In your example, `myClass.click("Test"); alert(myClass.data)`.  When you call `.click`, an AJAX request is fired, and when you alert `myClass.data` the request isn't done yet, so it's blank.